# Two-way data binding on large forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, data-binding

(After working through a React.js tutorial, I'm currently coding my first little app to get more practice. So this will be a newbie question and the answer is certainly out there somewhere, but apparently I don't know what to search for.)

Google lists a lot of examples on how to achieve two-way data binding for one input field. But what about large, complex forms, possibly with the option of adding more dynamically?

Let's say my form consists of horizontal lines of input fields. All lines are the same: First name, last name, date of birth and so on. At the bottom of the table, there is a button to insert a new such line. All this data is stored in an array. How do I bind each input field to its respective array element, so that the array gets updated when the user edits a value?

Working example with two lines of two columns each:

```js
import { useState} from 'react';

function App() {
    var [name1, setName1] = useState('Alice');
    var [score1, setScore1] = useState('100');
    var [name2, setName2] = useState('Bob');
    var [score2, setScore2] = useState('200');

    function changeNameHandler1 (e) {
        console.log(e)
        setName1(e.target.value)
    }

    function changeScoreHandler1 (e) {
        setScore1(e.target.value)
    }

    function changeNameHandler2 (e) {
        setName2(e.target.value)
    }

    function changeScoreHandler2 (e) {
        setScore2(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="name1" id="id1" type="text" value={name1} onChange={changeNameHandler1} /></td>
                        <td><input name="score1" type="text" value={score1} onChange={changeScoreHandler1} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="name2" type="text" value={name2} onChange={changeNameHandler2} /></td>
                        <td><input name="score2" type="text" value={score2} onChange={changeScoreHandler2} /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {name1} has a score of {score1}<br />
            {name2} has a score of {score2}<br />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How do I scale this up without having to add handler functions for hundreds of fields individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still store your fields in an object and then just add to the object when you want to add a field. Then map through the keys to display them.

Simple example:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [fields, setFields ] = useState({
    field_0: ''
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFields({
      ...fields,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const addField = () => setFields({
    ...fields,
    ['field_' + Object.keys(fields).length]: ''
  })

  const removeField = (key) => {
    delete fields[key]
    setFields({...fields})
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(fields).map(key => (
        <div>
          <input onChange={handleChange} key={key} name={key} value={fields[key]} />
          <button onClick={() => removeField(key)}>Remove Field</button>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => addField()}>Add Field</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(fields)}>Log fields</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is what I think you are trying to achieve in your question:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [fieldIndex, setFieldIndex] = useState(1)
  const [fields, setFields ] = useState({
    group_0: {
      name: '',
      score: ''
    }
  })

  const handleChange = (e, key) => {
    setFields({
      ...fields,
      [key]: {
        ...fields[key],
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  const addField = () => {
    setFields({
      ...fields,
      ['group_' + fieldIndex]: {
        name: '',
        score: ''
      }
    })
    setFieldIndex(i => i + 1)
  }

  const removeField = (key) => {
    delete fields[key]
    setFields({...fields})
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(fields).map((key, index) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <div>Group: {index}</div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, key)} name='name' value={fields[key].name} />
          <label>Score: </label>
          <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, key)} name='score' value={fields[key].score} />
          <button onClick={() => removeField(key)}>Remove Field Group</button>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => addField()}>Add Field</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(fields)}>Log fields</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You may want to keep the index for naming in which case you can use an array. Then you would just pass the index to do your input changing. Here is an example of using an array:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [fields, setFields ] = useState([
    {
      name: '',
      score: ''
    }
  ])

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    fields[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value
    setFields([...fields])
  }

  const addField = () => {
    setFields([
      ...fields,
        {
          name: '',
          score: ''
        }
    ])
  }

  const removeField = (index) => {
    fields.splice(index, 1)
    setFields([...fields])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {fields.map((field, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>Group: {index}</div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)} name='name' value={field.name} />
          <label>Score: </label>
          <input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)} name='score' value={field.score} />
          <button onClick={() => removeField(index)}>Remove Field Group</button>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => addField()}>Add Field</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(fields)}>Log fields</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Your original reply was already very enlightening. I had never seen this dot-dot-dot operator before, but it seems immensely useful.

But the second example is probably exactly what I needed - thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Steve, quick followup question: How would you implement a removeField handler?

Comment: @snorri I edited the answer with examples. I added an example of how you can just use an array because you may want to keep the groups indexed. Either way works. But if  you are going to use the object example then you will have to add an index state to avoid naming conflicts when adding and removing groups. So it may be better to use an array after all. Its up to you but I updated the answer to show you how to go about it. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

have multiple solutions to this problem for example:

Solution #1
Using useRef to store value of the field

```js
import { useRef, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const fullNameInputElement = useRef();
  const emailInputElement = useRef();
  const passwordInputElement = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmationInputElement = useRef();

  const formHandler = useCallback(
    () => (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const data = {
        fullName: fullNameInputElement.current?.value,
        email: emailInputElement.current?.value,
        password: passwordInputElement.current?.value,
        passwordConfirmation: passwordConfirmationInputElement.current?.value
      };

      console.log(data);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formHandler()}>
      <label htmlFor="full_name">Full name</label>
      <input
        ref={fullNameInputElement}
        id="full_name"
        placeholder="Full name"
        type="text"
      />

      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        ref={emailInputElement}
        id="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        type="email"
      />

      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input
        ref={passwordInputElement}
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        type="password"
      />

      <label htmlFor="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
      <input
        ref={passwordConfirmationInputElement}
        id="password_confirmation"
        placeholder="Password Confirmation"
        type="password"
      />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

or still use useState but store all values in one object

```js
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const initialUserData = {
  fullName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  passwordConfirmation: ""
};

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(initialUserData);

  const updateUserDataHandler = useCallback(
    (type) => (event) => {
      setUserData({ ...userData, [type]: event.target.value });
    },
    [userData]
  );

  const formHandler = useCallback(
    () => (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log(userData);
    },
    [userData]
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formHandler()}>
      <label htmlFor="full_name">Full name</label>
      <input
        id="full_name"
        placeholder="Full name"
        type="text"
        value={userData.fullName}
        onChange={updateUserDataHandler("fullName")}
      />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input
        id="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        type="email"
        value={userData.email}
        onChange={updateUserDataHandler("email")}
      />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        type="password"
        value={userData.password}
        onChange={updateUserDataHandler("password")}
      />
      <label htmlFor="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
      <input
        id="password_confirmation"
        placeholder="Password Confirmation"
        type="password"
        value={userData.passwordConfirmation}
        onChange={updateUserDataHandler("passwordConfirmation")}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Solution #2
Or you have multiple libraries that also provide solutions like `react-form-hook` https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: Oof, I think these are a bit too advanced for my level for now. I will come back to them once I have a somewhat firmer grasp of React. Thank you very much for your extensive reply!